# How to show an input on GUI tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I just want to make a simple table where the user inputs values for the mean, min, and max. This will then be displayed on GUI of Tkinter. I think I am almost there, but for some reason, I cannot seem to edit the label's I created.

```
from tkinter import * root = Tk() root.title("Simple Calculator")

out_mean = Label(root, text="Mean") 
out_min = Label(root, text="Min") 
out_max = Label(root, text="Max") #shows as text in the window

e_mean = Entry(root,width= 35, borderwidth = 5) 
e_min = Entry(root,width= 35, borderwidth = 5) 
e_max = Entry(root,width= 35, borderwidth = 5)

def click_mean(number):
    out_mean.delete(0, END)
    out_mean.insert(0, e_mean)

def click_min(number):
    out_min.delete(0, END)
    out_min.insert(0, e_min)

def click_max(number):
    out_max.delete(0, END)
    out_max.insert(0, e_max)

button_mean = Button(root, text = "mean", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: click_mean())  
button_min = Button(root, text = "min", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: click_min()) 
button_max = Button(root, text = "max", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = lambda: click_max())

e_mean.grid(row=0,column=0) 
e_min.grid(row=1,column=0) 
e_max.grid(row=2,column=0)

button_mean.grid(row=0,column=1) 
button_min.grid(row=1,column=1) 
button_max.grid(row=2,column=1)

out_mean.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan = 2) 
out_min.grid(row=1,column=2, columnspan = 2) 
out_max.grid(row=2,column=2, columnspan = 2)
```

Comment: @jezza_99 Sorry, you are right, I changed up the function names and didn't change the call. But even with your changes, the values don't get displayed on the right

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues with your code.

Firstly, your button command is not correct. You shouldn't need to use a lambda when you have already defined a function that needs no input. Your lambda functions are also not calling the correct function. At no point do you call any of `click_mean`, `click_min` or `click_max`.

Your second error is passing the Entry as an argument to alter the text, not the text entered into the entry. You need to call `e_mean.get()` to get the string value.

Your third error is that you are trying to edit the text values of the Labels as if they are Entries. The correct call is `<Label_name>.configure(text=e_mean.get())`.

Fixing all of these errors, your working code is now:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk() 
root.title("Simple Calculator")

out_mean = Label(root, text="Mean") 
out_min = Label(root, text="Min") 
out_max = Label(root, text="Max") #shows as text in the window

e_mean = Entry(root,width= 35, borderwidth = 5) 
e_min = Entry(root,width= 35, borderwidth = 5) 
e_max = Entry(root,width= 35, borderwidth = 5)

def click_mean():
    out_mean.configure(text=e_mean.get())
def click_min():
    out_min.configure(text=e_min.get())
def click_max():
    out_max.configure(text=e_max.get())

button_mean = Button(root, text = "mean", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = click_mean)  
button_min = Button(root, text = "min", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = click_min) 
button_max = Button(root, text = "max", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = click_max)

e_mean.grid(row=0,column=0) 
e_min.grid(row=1,column=0) 
e_max.grid(row=2,column=0)

button_mean.grid(row=0,column=1) 
button_min.grid(row=1,column=1) 
button_max.grid(row=2,column=1)

out_mean.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan = 2) 
out_min.grid(row=1,column=2, columnspan = 2) 
out_max.grid(row=2,column=2, columnspan = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

While not an error that you will be noticing (because tkinter is smart and can make do without) is that you aren't calling `root.mainloop()` at the end of your script. While not causing any errors currently, it is good practice to do so and can cause errors in some cases. You should also not use a wildcard import for tkinter (`from tkinter import *`). Instead explicitly define the import, `import tkinter as tk` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You changed up some of the things:

1. the lambdas called the objects
2. you didn't get the value of the entry properly
3. you changed up the entries and output widgets.

The final code:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

out_mean = Label(root, text="Mean") 
out_min = Label(root, text="Min") 
out_max = Label(root, text="Max") #shows as text in the window

e_mean = Entry(root,width= 30, borderwidth = 5) 
e_min = Entry(root,width= 30, borderwidth = 5) 
e_max = Entry(root,width= 30, borderwidth = 5)

def click_mean():
    out_mean.configure(text=e_mean.get())
    e_mean.delete(0, END)
def click_min():
    out_min.configure(text=e_min.get())
    e_mean.delete(0, END)

def click_max():
    out_max.configure(text=e_max.get())
    e_max.delete(0, END)

button_mean = Button(root, text = "mean", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = click_mean)  
button_min = Button(root, text = "min", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = click_min) 
button_max = Button(root, text = "max", padx = 40, pady = 20, command = click_max)

e_mean.grid(row=0,column=0) 
e_min.grid(row=1,column=0) 
e_max.grid(row=2,column=0)

button_mean.grid(row=0,column=1) 
button_min.grid(row=1,column=1) 
button_max.grid(row=2,column=1)

out_mean.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan = 2) 
out_min.grid(row=1,column=2, columnspan = 2) 
out_max.grid(row=2,column=2, columnspan = 2)

root.mainloop()
```